# Multiple values for one particular data in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a column with multiple values for a given condition .For eg., say I want to add more customer names to the same row where the country is Germany
EG:Customers Table

```
CustomerID CustomerName     ContactName       Address     City PostalCode Country
   89     White Clover        Karl      305-14th Ave.S.Suite 3B Seattle 98128 USA

INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName)
VALUES ('X'),('Y'),(Z);
SELECT Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country='Germany';
```

I tried UPDATE but it doesn't let me set more than one value.

Please let me know if there's a way to do this.

Comment: A single column & row doesn't hold more than 1 piece of data. Sounds like you want 2 tables with a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: If it was say a string you could do something like concatenate a comma separated list. But if data has commas in it you would be hosed. Better off 2 tables - per @Lamu suggestion. Much cleaner. And long term may save space. id's vs same string over and over...

Comment: @Larnu If I were to do the 2 tables with one-to-many relationship, how would I go about it?

Comment: What are you asking there exactly? How to create a table?